# Copy tables from mulitple RDS postgres instances to one postgres rds

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, pg-dump, debezium

I have 8 rds postgres instances, each supporting databases for the 8 solutions we have.

I would like to bring all the data in the 8 rds postgres instances to a single rds postgres instance.

This is needed for analytics

Here is my work on this until now:

1. Tried to download each table into a csv and upload them to the target rds instance. The copy command fails for a table that is of size 50GB. I am unable to migrate all the data at one shot and then set up incremental load. It fails at the full table load for large tables.(Using python here too)
2. Thought of using DMS , but it is recommended that for rds-postgres to rds-postgres migration, they recommend using pgdump and pgrestore instead of DMS. But for pgdump and pgrestore I need to store the password, and my organization does not let me do that
3. Using debezium, but this is a long process and I honestly, need this up and working very soon.

The ideal situation is where all the 8 databases in the 8 rds instances are replicated in the one rds postgres instance. And this should be continous replication. I am okay for batch processing for the time being(the data can be stale by a day). But if streaming (example - debezium) is the only way , then I am okay too..

Any thoughts on this please?

Comment: Upload a CSV is thr way to go. Find and fix the error.

Comment: okay. In this case, for the 50 GB table, I use the copy command to extract the data to csv, and after a while it errors out with this message 'canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User query might have needed to see row versions that must be removed.'

Comment: That's an entirely different problem: you are getting replication conflicts. Set `max_standby_streaming_delay = -1` on the standby.

Comment: okay.. so is it okay to use copy to download a table that is of size 50GB and every growing?

Comment: Sure, that's the tool of choice for this. `pg_dump` uses `COPY` to do that.

Comment: thanks Laurenz. However, the 50GB table will take a long time to download to a csv. Will this not cause bloating in my primary DB?

Comment: Of course. But the other methods will do that too. Perhaps you could restore the database from a backup somewhere else and use that as a source.

Comment: Thanks . One last question, will the setting of these parameters need to be done on the primary instance or the read replica?

Comment: On the replica.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. Let me try this out and get back

Comment: hi Laurenz. I made the changes on read replica. I created a new parameter group with the changes for max_standby_archive_delay = -1
max_standby_streaming_delay = -1
hot_standby_feedback = on                                                                                     
 and associated it to the replica. However, some of the articles on the internet say a restart of the rds is required.I do not have the option of restarting the replica, I can only restart my master.  So for these changes to reflect , is the reboot required on master?

Comment: Yes, you have to restart PostgreSQL on the standby. Not on the primary, though.

Comment: hi @LaurenzAlbe... I have set all the required db parameters and restarted the replica too.. And the data dump to csv was tested. It is observed that after crossing 25GB the download just hangs.. Is it because there is a file size limit on csv? Or is it because I am writing a cursor that fetches all the data and then writes to the csv and it hangs because of my laptop memory(I am running this code on macbook pro with 8Gb memory)?